# How do I know whether my graphic drivers are installed or not

Tags: drivers, ati

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my lenovo laptop and found a "chip" image on the top of the screen. It showed me to install 3 drivers

1. ATI/AMD Proprietary FGLRX graphics drivers (post-release updates)
2. Broadcom STA wireless drivers
3. ATI/AMD Proprietary FGLRX graphics drivers

When I installed 1st one, it showed me some error so, I installed 2nd one it was successful. I went to 3rd and it failed 1st time and later it worked.. After when I came back and found that it isn't not installed.

I think these are for my ATI Radeon graphic drivers but don't know why its happening.
If even found the "System Info" isn't showing any information about graphics.

So, how do I know whether my graphics are installed or not and if not how do I?

Comment: For the record, the second driver is for your wireless network adapter and has nothing to do with your graphics card.

Comment: The error messages are important. They give clues as to the problem. without them people cannot answer but can only guess. When you log in do you have two options - Ubuntu and Ubuntu 2D? If you have the Ubuntu option then your proprietary graphic driver is activated. In the past the Additional Driver utility would say: "Activated but not in use." That is a false message. If you have that message ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running `fgl_glxgears`. If the driver is correctly installed, you should see an animation of a cube looking like this:

[image: fgl_gears]

If you get an error, that means the driver is either incorrectly installed, or not installed at all. In order to install it, follow [these instructions](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29).

Comment: nope, its showing error.

Comment: In that case, follow the instructions in the link above. I have recently installed these drivers myself by following said instructions, so I can vouch for their excellency. Also, what's the error?

Comment: I forgot to copy that.. All I could understand from it is that, it couldn't recognize :(

Comment: I will add a comment as soon as I install those drivers as mentioned in the instructions

Comment: @Carborundum cool tip about the cube.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add the Terminal command:

lsmod

to the conversation, to show what kernel modules are installed.

lsmod | grep video

specifically for video module.